# Reg Exp: match specific number of characters or digits

Tags: regex

My RegExp is very rusty! I have two questions, related to the following RegExp

**Question Part 1**

I'm trying to get the following RegExp to work

```
^.*\d{1}\.{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{5}.*$
```

What I'm trying to pass is  `x1.1SMITHx`  or `x1.1.JONESx`

Where `x` can be anything of any length but the  `SMITH` or `JONES` part of the input string is checked for 5 upper case characters **only**

So:

```
some preamble 1.1SMITH some more characters 123
xyz1.1JONES some more characters 123
```

both pass

But

```
another bit of string1.1SMITHABC some more characters 123
xyz1.1ME some more characters 123
```

Should not pass because `SMITH` now contains 3 additional characters, `ABC`, and `ME` is only 2 characters.
I only pass if after 1.1 there are 5 characters only

**Question Part 2**

How do I match on specific number of digits ?
Not bothered what they are, it's the number of them that I can't get working

if I use `^\d{1}$` I'd have thought it'll only pass if one digit is present

It will pass `5` but it also passes `67`

It should fail `67` as it's two digits in length.
The RegExp should pass only if 1 digit is present.

Comment: Part 2: I'd say  [it's probably your code](http://3v4l.org/GTPhB).

Comment: well thank you, of course it's my code, that's what I'm trying to get working. I've tried this in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Do you think your title can be useful for future readers?

Comment: `{1}` is redundant - unless you specifically add a `*`, `+` or `{}`, there may only be one occurrence.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to fix some code where `67` passes `^\d{1}$` if we aren't allowed to see it. It's like complaining that you do `1+1` and get `3`—it's possible if your code has a bug but you won't solve it looking at the raw equation.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, check out this regex:

```
^.*\d\.\d[A-Z]{5}[^A-Z]*$
```

Before solving the problem, I made it easier to read by removing all of the `{1}`. This is an unnecessary qualifier since regex will default to looking for one character (`/abc/` matches `abc` not `aaabbbccc`).

To fix the issue, we just need to replace your final `.*`. This says match 0+ characters of anything. If we make this "dot-match-all" more specific (i.e. `[^A-Z]`), you won't match `SMITHABC`.

Comment: thank you. The problem is the RegEx is auto generated from an old c++ app, I'm trying to debug. That's why the statement is not that efficient. The c++ app intern gets a list of rules generated from an old PERL app !

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a number of solution but I like these most. If your RegEx engine supports negative look-ahead and negative look-behind, you can use this:

```
Part 1: (?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{5}(?![A-Z])
Part 2: (?<!\d)\d(?!\d)
```

Both have a pattern of `(?<!expr)expr(?!expr)`.

- `(?<!...)` is a negative look-behind, meaning the match isn't preceded by the expression in the bracket.
- `(?!...)` is a negative look-ahead, meaning the match isn't followed by the expression in the bracket.

So: for the first pattern, it means "find 5 uppercase characters that are neither preceded nor followed by another uppercase character". In other words, match exactly 5 uppercase characters.

The second pattern works the same way: find a digit that is not preceded or followed by another digit.

You can try it on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7kV7/1).